# Search text contents of local html files

Tags: html

Looking for programs to choose from that will search the text contents of locally stored html files.  And it would be even better if they could search the contents of other file types too, but html ability is needed most.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Wouldn’t any search program that can search the contents be sufficient? Is there anything specific about HTML files that you need?

Comment: Thanks guys.  I didn't realize my Win7 did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Vista and Seven's built-in search does HTML files just fine.

Comment: Duh!  Didn't know that.  Thanks a lot.